# Bootstrap: how to truly center an image in a column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to put 4 images in 4 stacked columns using Bootstrap. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The 4 images align to the left top (on a large screen), what I want is to align them vertically and horizontally in the center, regardless any changes of image width or height, how can I do it? I did my search online but nothing seems to truly solve the problem.

Comment: Bootstrap comes with a range of classes that you can apply out of the box to center an object - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can do it with flexbox.

Add to your `col-md-6`

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way, making it responsive:

Add to your css:

```css
.rounded{
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution does not work if I change the width of the 2nd image to 100%, it only aligns the image to the center horizontally but not vertically

Answer (score 1):

use class `text-center` to column div

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:lavender">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I change width of the 2nd image to 100%, your solution only aligns the 1st image to center horizontally but not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code...you can just use `margin-left:25%;`. use `img` tag for all images. You can also use image `class="text-center"`

```css
img {
  margin-left:25%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;float:middle">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" style="width:50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will maybe help you. Please check below example.**

```css
.image-center {
            position: relative;
          }
          .image-center:after {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-bottom: 100%;
            content: "";
          }
          .image-center img {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            margin: auto;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            max-width: 70%;
            max-height: 70%;
          }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
                            <div class="image-center">
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender">
                            <div class="image-center">
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender">
                            <div class="image-center">
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
                            <div class="image-center">
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@gionic solves the problem. Others won't work in this case:

```css
.col-md-6{
  display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <h3>Align the 4 images to the center horizontally and vertically, even with height change of some images, rest images should still in the center.</h3>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="testImageCenter.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" 
       style="width:70%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" 
       style="width:40%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" 
       style="width:80%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="rounded" alt="flower" 
       style="width:100%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

With changes in height of some images, @gionic 's answer aligns all images to the center both horizontally and vertically.

Thanks all!